# Change the "^" keybinding prefix

Tags: key-bindings, prefix-keys

Some keybindings require you to type the `^` character (ie magit smerge) and for starters, on an UE AZERTY keyboard (which is a very bad layout design BTW) there are *two* of those, and they each input a different character.

One is for accentuating a letter, like this : êôû and the other is the right one: `^` obtained by pressing `altGr+key` so it's a sort of keybinding inception: A keybinding within a keybinding :)

Is there a way to replace the prefix char with a more accessible *single keypress* char altogether system-wide ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the function that sets the keybindings for magit-smerge.  You can redefine the keybindings by copying and modifying the `^` in the `define-key` lines.

```
(defun magit-smerge-setup ()
  "Setup magit-smerge keybindings."
  (interactive)
  (define-key magit-hunk-section-map (kbd "C-c ^ l") #'magit-smerge-keep-lower)
  (define-key magit-hunk-section-map (kbd "C-c ^ u") #'magit-smerge-keep-upper))
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want, where `X` is whatever single key you want?

```lisp
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "^") (kbd "X"))
```

But what you really want probably depends on which keymap `^` is bound as a prefix key in. Your question doesn't provide any context.